# Why the first funcion give me results and second one only undefined?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

The result should be the same but the second function gives me undefined.

```
        fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1").then(res => res.json()).then(json => json.results).then(console.log).catch(console.error); // {user: xyz, ... }


   const getFakePerson = async () => {
      try {
        let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
        let {results} = res.json();
        console.log(results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
     }; 
   } 
    getFakePerson(); // Undefined
```

Can it someone please explain to me?

Comment: You need to call the functions `log` and `error` in the first part. I know it doesn't change anything for the second, but still

Comment: @expressjs123 The functions are called when the callback is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async function returns always an promise. `res.json()` aswell

Instead of resolving the promise like `resolve("some data")` you need to `return` to resolve the promise

```js
const getFakePerson = async () => {
      try {
        let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
        let { results } = await res.json();
        return results;
      } catch (error) {
      }; 
    } 
    getFakePerson().then(res => console.log(res))
```

A better approach would be:

```js
const getFakePerson = async () => {
   return fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => res.results)
}

getFakePerson()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: I do think the first version is a lot more readable

Comment: @mplungjan yea. i jus explain why his second approach doesnt work

Comment: @mplungjan don't focus on readable if your trying to use that data in continuous code it will be problamatic so 2nd method help you to get the data and access in current scope

Comment: @Ashish But your code on your answer does look far too complicated with too many awaits in my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan it provides proper output just by calling function.

Comment: @Ashish So does the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can work something like this

```js
fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1").then(res => res.json()).then(json => json.results).then(console.log).catch(console.error); // 


const getFakePerson = async() => {
  try {
    let res = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=1");
    let json = await res.json();
    let result = json.results;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  };
}
console.log(getFakePerson());
```

Comment: The output shown when executing the stack snippet is a bit misleading. `getFakePerson()` returns a Promise, not the actual result.